# CakePHP: Ask user to enter password when entering account

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I make a user have to re-enter their password when they access their account? So for example: `domain.com/account` and then they see a simple password field (even though they are logged in) if they get the password wrong then they are logged out and sent to the home page with a session message saying 'for security reasons you have been logged out of your account'.

Can anyone help?

The account is the edit method in my users controller.

Thanks

Comment: What Cakephp version you are using?

Comment: 1.3.8. Why does that matter for this though? Thanks

Comment: Many are already shifting to 2.0 so just wanted to clarify it. Have you tried anything yet? Like just making a post form that has the password field and then use the hashpassword function to hash it and compare with logged in users hashed password?

Comment: Haven't tried anything because I have no idea how to do it :P if you could show how to do what you have explained in your comment i'll give it a try and post any issues I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this ~

```
// edit.ctp View
echo $this->Form->input('password_check', array('type'=>'password'));

// user.php Model
function check_user_password($get_the_current_users_id) { 
    $salt = Configure::read('Security.salt');
    $this->User->id = $get_the_current_users_id;
    $hashed_password = $this->User->field('password');
    // check password  
    if($hashed_password == md5($data['User']['password_check'].$salt)) {  
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'd need to adjust the password hashing bit; if you don't use the salt etc.

But the idea is to compare the users hashed password in the database, to the one they submit. If it matches; then you can proceed. Else, you can logout/return an error. (For usability I would **not** log out a user as that would just be annoying.)

Comment: What do I put in my controller to show either the password field or the edit profile view?

Comment: Basic if/else statement; perhaps using `$this->render` to avoid changing the action. Set a session if they authenticate. Why go to all this trouble? It's breaking convention to have a user re-enter a password just to ACCESS his account after logging in. I could understand asking for password confirmation AFTER making sensitive changes; but you're just making extra work for your user.

Comment: It's a client request. They saw something similar on the MobileMe website and wanted to implement it on the app I'm developing for them. I'm still not fully understanding how to use the code you have posted though. Would you be able to show the controller code as well and how to use the function posted? Much appreciated. Thanks